# Covert XSD schema to GraphQL schema

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, graphql

looking to replace a large number of XSD schemas with GraphQL schemas, is there any automated tool to do this? Would rather not do it manually if possible.

Cheers

Comment: They're...really different and describe very different things.  (GraphQL has no equivalent of the Unique Particle Attribution Constraint.)

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this and can't vouch for it, but

https://github.com/Confbase/schema

looks like something that might help.